# Serialize to class namespace issue

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

So I have this XML string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<options>
 <option category="Fabric" descriptiveName="BLUSH" grade="B">
    <optionProductID category="cover">
        <id optionIDQualifier="SellerAssigned" optionID="BLUSH" />
    </optionProductID>
    <optionQuantity unitOfMeasure="Each" value="1" />
    <optionPrice>899</optionPrice>
    <optionRetailPrice>899</optionRetailPrice>
    <sequenceNumber>0</sequenceNumber>
    <areaName>BODY</areaName>
    <areaCode />
 </option>
 <option category="Fabric" descriptiveName="597" grade="B">
    <optionProductID category="cover">
        <id optionIDQualifier="SellerAssigned" optionID="597" />
    </optionProductID>
    <optionQuantity unitOfMeasure="Each" value="1" />
    <optionPrice>20</optionPrice>
    <optionRetailPrice>20</optionRetailPrice>
    <sequenceNumber>0</sequenceNumber>
    <areaName>BACK CUSHION WELT</areaName>
    <areaCode />
 </option>
</options>
```

And I created these classes:

```
 public class options
         {
            public List<option> option { get; set; }
         }

public class option
    {
                    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
                    public string category { get; set; }
                    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
                    public string descriptiveName { get; set; }
                    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute]
                    public string grade { get; set; }
                    public string optionPrice { get; set; }
                    public string areaName { get; set; }
    }
```

And I try to deserialize it like so:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(options));
System.IO.StringReader rdr = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlstring);
options resultingMessage = (options)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
```

I need to deserialize this XML string into this class but keep running into issues, what am I doing wrong here?

Currently I get this error:

```
<option xmlns=''> was not expected.
```

Comment: Did you use xsd.exe to create your model?

Comment: no, I looked at the string and wrote what I thought I needed - I never deal with XML, not a fan and clueless about it

Answer (score 0):

I think the class options' instance name should be same as root node object name,

```
     public class options
     {
        public List<option> options { get; set; }
     }
```